# Need multiple sound outputs to multiple speakers

Tags: c#, audio

How do I play 3 different music tracks at the same time on my computer, such that song1 is played in speaker1, song2 in speaker2...

Is this possible programatically? What additional hardware will I need? Do I need 3 seperate sound cards? Given that the hardware is in place, how would I "route" the sound output for a particular song to a particular speaker.

Alternatively, is there a special hardware that can handle multiple inputs and outputs?

Appreciate your expert opinions.

Comment: Welcome to P.SE... but I'm not sure this question is on-topic here, as its more of a hardware question

Comment: I wasn't sure about the categorization myself. There's both programming and hardware knowledge involved here. Should I delete it then?

Comment: don't worry... your friendly moderators have moved it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.esi-audio.com/products/maya44usb+/ Try this with the NAudio c# Libary look at AsioOut and the MultiplexingWaveProvider

Comment: Looks awesome. Any idea about the price in USD?

Answer (score 0):

Provided that you have as many outputs (total) as you have songs you are all set (I'm assuming you'll just be playing each song in mono). The simplest way to tackle this problem is to open one "stream" for each song and play the song through that stream. You'll have to do some work to open each stream with the right number of channels and ensure that the song is played in the correct channel.

There are two potential problems with that technique: 1. some audio API/hardware combinations don't allow multiple streams to access the same device. This is most commonly an issue on windows/ASIO, but it may be an issue in other cases -- I am not a windows expert. 2. it is a bit tricky to ensure that all streams are exactly synchronized. If you require tight synchronization you should use a single stream and a single hardware device.

If the above issues are a concern, then you should get some audio hardware with at lest three outputs, and open one stream with access to three channels.

You can use PortAudio for audio I/O, and libsoundfile for reading the sound files (of course, there are other options for both these tasks).

Comment: Thanks Bjorn. I should have mentioned, I would be doing that on the windows platform and preferably in the .NET framework. Anyway, your briefing does give it a direction, thanks.

Comment: I don't use it myself, but I am told people use PortAudio with .NET. Anyway, good luck! Dunno about libsoundfile.